# Tweak for using Preg_Match() on Phone numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am using `preg_match` to extract the various sections of a US-based phone number from within a paragraph of text. **I can already extract the number.** But I want to make `match[0]` include only the phone numbers.

**Problem:** My pattern comes close, but I need some help to get rid of whatever text is before the phone number. How do I get rid of the preceding string `"Hey my phone is "`?

**PHP Code**

```
$pattern = '/.*?(?:1(?:[. -])?)?(?:\((?=\d{3}\)))?([2-9]\d{2})'
    .'(?:(?<=\(\d{3})\))? ?(?:(?<=\d{3})[.-])?([2-9]\d{2})'
    .'[. -]?(\d{4})(?: (?i:ext)\.? ?(\d{1,5}))?.*?/';;

$subject = 'Hey my phone is 911-628-4539, call me tonight at 9:16:00pm, my room is 122-1001';

preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match);

print_r($match);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => Hey my phone is 911-628-4539 [1] => 911 [2] => 628 [3] => 4539 )
```

Comment: You should use the `/x` [PCRE_EXTENDED flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for readability. Use `\s` for the few places you actually need a space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove : `.*?`

from your regex. If you don't need it why match it?

Comment: Moreover, `.*?` is redundant and could be reduced to `.*` if it were needed at all. @Nyxynyx You should also remove it from the end of your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You capture the text part, because you match it. It's the leading `.*?` which does that.

Either remove that, or add `\K` right behind it.